# Postman Generate Valid Token, C# Web Client Token from Newtonsoft JToken doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to get the token from OAuth 2.0 Server and then pass to REST API with `Authorization` header.
It gets the token from the server and upon API call, it says the Token is Invalid.

Using token generated from Postman, and calling rest API from postman by that token works fine. Even if I try to paste the token generated by C# Client in Postman, Postman Rest API informed token is invalid.

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 and generating token like this.

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
    { "resource", baseUrl.Value.Replace("/commerce", "").Trim() },
    { "client_id", Startup.Configuration["clientId"] },
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
    { "client_secret", Startup.Configuration["clientSecret"] }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var responseString = await client.PostAsync(tenantUrl.Value + "/oauth2/token", content);
string responseBody = await responseString.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject resJson = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
string token = resJson["access_token"].ToString();
```

Passing the Token to REST API by the following code.

When I insert token generated from POSTMAN, the REST API returns fine. There is some problem in C# Web Client Token Generation.

```
client = new HttpClient();
var tt = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var ounHeader = request.Headers.Where(m => m.Key == "OUN").FirstOrDefault();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(ounHeader.Key, ounHeader.Value.First());

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

var rsActionResponse = await client.PostAsync(oDataRequest, tt);
responseBody = await rsActionResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject rsActionResponseJSON = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
```

**Token from Postman (Working) :**

`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImlCakwxUmNxemhpeTRmcHhJeGRacW9oTTJZayIsImtpZCI6ImlCakwxUmNxemhpeTRmcHhJeGRacW9oTTJZayJ9.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.fWJiUaOmPuRD21EcuGnUBWCNYl0TaUZ7OxIFQXHYmMvnivHiys5j9UjL3ZBRSZAVzrjrBS-v-0xyyzT_502NEkM0H77vnaxXFB2lrZz1GRcXr5oFSW4gfDTvPinByLr5LBglxZG6_PCP4oqChKQgigxR7xBjok1XXQOD2_h-gYZbmnDNexjzkxZAl4kqTCfSfoRJxUZxX1pgD5PRAAkx1eanc1jiJ4KQA6kvnSDL0PyGGmmQe36RrMKH5bclH3sMLO3wilgvLMp3ekKDj51P2emW9dhDx2BrblowpCcLGe3Q6PikuZrYOkx44WqJKAS6QovJwijxCEq9XKAzDEZbig`

**Token from C# Web Client (Not Working)**

`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImlCakwxUmNxemhpeTRmcHhJeGRacW9oTTJZayIsImtpZCI6ImlCakwxUmNxemhpeTRmcHhJeGRacW9oTTJZayJ9.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.Bulbv3HZyufQevjMPI-OU5_0NCrtFXPU9PIxXHriWLg_Mj_uUtoFHVslUtNH4FTwMEq2lTheE87N5jDkTra3Z-aTOQhsj3sz-6wqA4HrDGpbPyHaGscFfHkitpUyzV4_HfLaVA4vWAHbwKEIqs1gaVp-81m3oMka0OmDh1Jjgg-Lvcr-TMOkdP1qsgSdcRmqVWwmjYTp7HSPS997poC54md_Bdx7hFRwEA7WNmCdSCLZ44izgFHb3ou47r3agXprERYDBo6Vi6ofSp4zAsvYdsxoFrM6LiOwWSKbqilYotgDKjUQpA7u41iwy6fjgV1wBerOJUBWCWN8w3Vs4cmhXA`

Comment: Do you use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?  If so, try to compare what differences you get in request/response.

Comment: Are you using the same OAuth grant with Postman? Also, can you add example tokens from your code and from postman?

Comment: Could you create a sample project it upload it to GitHub?

Comment: @MarkG Yes i use Fiddler, Fiddler record the postman request but isnt recording request from this app ( using IIS express) - is there any way to record that request also

Comment: @MarcLaFleur i have edited the post and posted the working and non working token - as they are different everytime generated.

Comment: @Win this is the complete code for web client only. I cant write the url and client id , secret due to security reasons.

Comment: @ShanKhan It's possible you have to set Fiddler as your proxy.  An alternative is to copy your code to a simple console app for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: I really don't want it to be this but.... so the only real difference between the two tokens is a trailing `/` on the `aud` claim in the working token. Could you try adding a trailing `/` to your `baseUrl` ( `baseUrl.Value.Replace("/commerce", "").Trim()`)?

Comment: Thanks, i have fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed:

1. Token was received from Url : `www.xyz.com`
2. URL was registered as `www.xyz.com/`
3. Need to call `www.xyz.com/` to get the valid token and pass to other API methods.

There is difference between `www.xyz.com/` and `www.xyz.com` in OAuth registered.